# Brillo (Android things) with weave

Tags: android, android-things, weave, brillo

I'm new in this field of Android things(Brillo) and weave protocol

I have Android Things OS image installed for my Rasp3 and successfully booted up and log in to shell using adb, everything fine and the simple example of LED was successfully worked .

So my question is

How to integrate weave to android things image in raspberry pi 3?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, yet.

Because of the pivot (Brillo to Android Things: https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/announcing-googles-new-internet-of-things-platform-with-weave-and-android-things.html) a few things need to be done from scratch.

You can work and experiment with Weave already, though!

The best place is probably the website, as soon something new happens they will post it there!